# Knockout JS ObservableArray losing values

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout. I'm successfully pulling data, but trying to filter it based on whether the record is active or not active. When I do this, it's sending the right values through, but my observable array is empty.

I'm filling it with ajax. My understanding is that I fill the observable array, and do not need to do any other hits to the server unless I want to write to the database or get new data. So once that observable array has data, I should be able to filter it without hitting the database again. This doesn't seem to work for me. I think I'm doing something wrong. Thoughts?

Here is the code:

```js
var sgsoip = window.sgsoip || {};
sgsoip.FunctionalAreaViewModel = function (ko, db) {
    //'use strict';
    var self = this;
    self.functionalAreas = ko.observableArray([])

    self.headers = [
        { title: '', sortPropertyName: '', asc: true },
        { title: 'Functional Area Name', sortPropertyName: 'FunctionalAreaName', asc: true },
        { title: 'Active', sortPropertyName: 'FunctionalAreaActive', asc: true }
    ];
    self.filters = [
        { title: "Show All", filter: null },
        { title: "Active", filter: function (item) { return item.FunctionalAreaActive == 'true'; } },
        { title: "Inactive", filter: function (item) { return item.FunctionalAreaActive == 'false'; } }
    ];

    self.activeFilter = ko.observable(self.filters[0].filter);

    self.setActiveFilter = function (model, event) {
        self.activeFilter(model.filter);
    }

    self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.activeFilter()) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.functionalAreas, self.activeFilter()); //When hitting filter self.functionalAreas is empty
        } else {
            return self.functionalAreas(); //this works as expected
        }
    });

    self.activeSort = self.headers[1];
    function _init() {
        db.getFunctionalAreas(function (data) {
            //var a = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data || [], function (item) {
                self.functionalAreas.push(new sgsoip.FunctionalArea(item.FunctionalAreaID, item.FunctionalAreaName, item.FunctionalAreaActive));
            });
            //self.functionalAreas(a);
        });
    }
    
    _init();
    return {
        functionalAreas: functionalAreas,
        sortedFunctionalAreas: sortedFunctionalAreas,
        removeFunctionalArea: removeFunctionalArea
    };
}(ko, sgsoip.DataContext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-bind="foreach: filters">
        <button class="btn btn-small" data-bind="click: setActiveFilter, text: title"></button>
    </div>

    <table class="table" id="gridoutput">
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
                <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: filteredItems, text: title"></a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: removeFunctionalArea" title="Delete"><i class="icon icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                <td data-bind="text: FunctionalAreaName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: FunctionalAreaActive"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Edit - Added some missing stuff for those that asked.

```js
var sgsoip = window.sgsoip || {};
sgsoip.DataContext = (function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var me = {
        getFunctionalAreas: getFunctionalAreas,
        removeFunctionalArea: removeFunctionalArea,
        saveFunctionalArea: saveFunctionalArea
    };
    function getFunctionalAreas(callback) {
        var functionalareas = null;
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            //functionalareas = localStorage["functionalareas"];
            //alert('test');

            //if (functionalareas != "undefined") {
            //    callback(functionalareas);
            //} else {
            $.getJSON('/FunctionalAreas/GetJsonData', function (data) {
                    //localStorage["functionalareas"] = JSON.stringify(data.FunctionalAreas);
                callback(data);
                });
            //}
        }
    }

    function removeFunctionalArea(functionalArea) {

    }

    function saveFunctionalArea(functionalArea) {

    }
    return me;
})(jQuery);


var sgsoip = window.sgsoip || {};
sgsoip.FunctionalArea = function (FunctionalAreaID, FunctionalAreaName, FunctionalAreaActive) {
    'use strict';
    this.FunctionalAreaID = ko.observable(FunctionalAreaID);
    this.FunctionalAreaName = ko.observable(FunctionalAreaName).extend({ required: "Functional Area Name is required" });
    this.FunctionalAreaActive = ko.observable(FunctionalAreaActive).extend({ required: "Active is required" });
    this.HasError = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return this.FunctionalAreaActive.hasError() || this.FunctionalAreaName.hasError();
    }, this);
};
```

**EDIT**
Looks like I can add more clarification. It is not losing data. I stepped all the way through the Knockout code. And it does cycle through the observable to compare.

I get to the following piece of code:

```js
arrayFilter: function (array, predicate) {
            array = array || [];
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
                if (predicate(array[i], i))
                    result.push(array[i]);
            return result;
        },
```

And it never executes the result.push(array[i]) line.

Comment: your sample doesn't define `db` or `FunctionalArea`; I'm trying to test this out in a fiddle. can you provide a self-contained working example?

Comment: To an extent I can. But you'd have to replace my json call with static json I guess. One sec. I'll update the post.

Comment: it doesn't even have to be an ajax call, just include the data and set it in the _init method

Comment: when you debug that last bit of code you added, what do the values `array[i]` and `i` look like before being passed to `predicate`? are they equal?

Comment: Well, array[i] is an object. it has a number of functions in it. If I look in FunctionalAreaActive (the one I'm filtering by) it shows "_latestValue" is "true" which means it should be returned. Meanwhile, i is just the number, so obviously on the first time through it's 0, second is 1, etc.

Comment: In console, I type predicate(array[i], 0) and receive false. predicate is function (item) { return item.FunctionalAreaActive == 'true'; } So.. at this point I'm just not familiar with this level of JS to be able to troubleshoot what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating or in any other way working with your observable array, you need to remember to add the parenthesis at the end, like so:

```
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.functionalAreas(), self.activeFilter());
```

It's only when using methods that are actually implemented on the observableArray (like push, remove etc), that you can leave out the parenthesis.

Comment: I thought so as well, even though the example I followed did not have it: http://ryanrahlf.com/filtering-table-data-with-knockout-js/  I made the change and still get the same result. It's as if any action after the initial page load clears the Observablearray.

Comment: After a few days. This ended up being correct, but a little different than the comment. It led to the correct answer. Despite many examples showing this working without () online, it did not work for me. I'm using knockout-3.4.0. The problem was in my self.filters array, I did not use () on this line - return item.FunctionalAreaActive() === true; and that caused it to fail.

Comment: In fact, yesterday I watched John Papa's presentation on knockout on youtube and he specifically said that knockout is smart enough to understand when a property does not have () on the end of it so long as it is the trailing property. He stated that thing.whatever is the same as thing.whatever() but something like thing.anotherthing.whatever is not valid, but thing.anotherthing().whatever is. If that makes sense. So either knockout is more restrictive than when he gave his talk, or something else is afoot here.

Comment: Well, knockout itself is smart enough, most of the time you don't need to add the () in the bindings, but when in plain JS, you do. At least that's my experience!